# You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.

Tags: footnotes, fancyvrb

I get a strange error with a `\Verb` escape in a footnote:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
Works inline \Verb!S#Var! but doesn't in footnote.
% \footnote{No really, it doesn't \Verb!S#Var! you see.}
\end{document}
```

When I uncomment the footnote line, the complaint is:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fun exercise. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch,fancyvrb,xparse}
\makeatletter
\let\do@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\regexpatchcmd{\do@footnotetext}
  {\c{insert}\c{footins}\cB.(.*)\cE.}
  {\1\c{egroup}}
  {}{}
\def\@footnotetext{\insert\footins\bgroup\@makeother\#\do@footnotetext}
\newcommand{\ttvar}{\begingroup\@makeother\#\@ttvar}
\newcommand{\@ttvar}[1]{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textheight}{3cm} % just to shorten the height for the example

\begin{document}
Works inline \ttvar{S#Var} and also in footnote.%
\footnote{Yes, \ttvar{S#Var}, as you see.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\detokenize` you can print all characters, except backslashes and `%` (actually backslashes are allowed, but they might produce unwanted spaces), so long as braces are balanced.

The trick is to modify `\@footnotetext` not to absorb its argument, but just doing `\insert\footins\bgroup`, changing the category code of `#` (you quite certainly won't be defining commands in a footnote) and calling `\do@footnotetext` that will absorb the argument. Somebody might enjoy looking how `\regexpatch` does its work on a copy of the original `\@footnotetext`.

The command `\ttvar` will locally change the category code of `#`.

---

#### Alternative solution.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb,cprotect}
\begin{document}
Works inline \Verb!S#Var! and also in footnote.%
\cprotect\footnote{Yes, \Verb!S#Var!, as you see.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The hash character can be escaped it seems:

```
\footnote{No really, it doesn't \Verb!S\#Var!}
```

Comment: You can not use verb in a macro argument that is just `\texttt(S\#Var}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually `\Verb` doesn't throw an error, but I believe the result will be unpredictable, in general.